# Amortentia - can smell change?

Tags: harry-potter, potions

I was reading  some fanfiction and there was some talk about Love Potion and that I started thinking about Amortentia. Now in Harry Potter lore it says that potion smells diferently for every person reminding each person of the things that they find most attractive.

> Hermione Granger smells fresh cut grass, new parchment, spearmint
>   toothpaste, and Ron Weasley's hair. Harry Potter smelled treacle tart,
>   the woody scent of broomstick handle, and "something flowery that he
>   thought he might have smelled at the Burrow"

So my question is if the Amortentia smells like the person who you are attracted to, and you drink it will the smell change? Since Amortentia is most powerful love potion there is, it creates powerful infatuation or obsession so strong that it has to change attraction as well. Now if attraction is changed so should smells, right? Or are the smell permanent and perhaps even defense mechanism or the potion so even if you are forced to drink it ever day it would still have chance to remind you who you love really.

Now I tried searching for answer on internet, I'm huge fan of Harry Potter so I know answer is not in books but I'm not so active on Pottermore ans such websites so I might have missed answer for this. Can anyone help? :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Yes, almost certainly**

You can surmise the answer from everything you've posted. The smell of the potion would from our knowledge change as your attraction changes.

If you are under the effects of Amortentia already your attraction cannot change you are magically induced to "love" that person. The person supplying you with potion may stop giving it to you in which case you may or may not stop loving them.

The only instance we see of this is when Merope Gaunt stops giving a general love potion (unclear which love potion) to Tom Riddle Sr and he runs away from her.

If you mean though that if you like person A and smell the potion and it smells like person A's perfume and then person B gives you the love potion it seems reasonable to conclude that the potion would henceforth smell like person B. This comes from my assumption that the potion works by detecting and altering the same chemical signals in your brain.

Comment: Where in canon does it say that the love potion Merope Gaunt used on Tom Riddle was Amortentia?

Comment: Yup, it doesn't, they just say Love Potion or  Imperius Curse..

Comment: @Slytherincess ah, you're not wrong. I will clarify that I'm referring to a general love potion in that instance ty! Maybe a discussion for chat but do we have any info on what the different Effectiveness's of the varying love portions are?